# In Makefile, ifeq seems to see a variable as combined with comments following the set value

Tags: makefile

I have this Makefile.

```
HFLOAT = 1 # comment
$(info $(HFLOAT))
ifeq ($(HFLOAT), 1)
$(info HFLOAT is 1)
endif
```

If I run 'make', it gives me

```
id@host:~/test] make
1 
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Oh, the `ifeq (..)` result was a false! so "HFLOAT is 1" is not printed.

But if I remove the `# comment` above in the Makefile, and rut make, I get

```
id@host:~/test] make
1
HFLOAT is 1
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

The `$(info ..)` printed HFLOAT value correct in both cases, but `ifeq ($(HFLOAT), 1)` seems to take the `# comment` as part of $(HFLOAT). What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From GNU make manual:

> ...if you do not want any whitespace characters at the end of your
>   variable value, you must remember not to put a random comment on the
>   end of the line after some whitespace...

Because of your comment, the value of `HFLOAT` is `1` followed by one space character. This is because the assigned value is everything right to the `=` sign, leading spaces stripped, and up to `#` (excluded). Your `ifeq` test thus fails. Without the comment and, **more important**, without the trailing space, the value of `HFLOAT` is `1` (just one) and the test passes.

Note that with:

```
HFLOAT = 1  # comment
```

the value of `HFLOAT` is `1` followed by **two** spaces. Note also that without the comment the trailing spaces can be difficult to spot but still there. With (use your mouse to select the line and see the trailing spaces):

```
HFLOAT = 1
```

the value of `HFLOAT` is also `1` followed by **two** spaces. When using conditionals like `ifeq` it is frequently wise to also use `strip` to remove leading and trailing spaces:

```
ifeq ($(strip $(HFLOAT)),1)
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks for a very kind explanation! I wasn't aware of that important thing.